# Uncheck check list box programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox

I need to uncheck checked checkbox programmatically, but the check list is in dialog. Does this changes solution? What I have so far:

```
CharSequence[] items = itemList.toArray(new CharSequence[itemList.size()]);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select categories");

builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
  if (isChecked){
    if(chosenCat.size() < 10){
      chosenCat.add(items[which].toString());
    }else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Max 10 categories to compare.",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      //uncheck
      items.isChecked = false; // --> wrong
      chosenCat.remove(items[which].toString());
    }
  }else{
    chosenCat.remove(items[which].toString());
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always use `.setChecked(false);`

Example:

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);

myCheckBox.setChecked(false); // false = uncheck it, true = check it
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that is AlertDialog.

Answer (score 2):

A [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) has both an [isChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29) and a [setChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29) method. Those are sufficient to achieve what you want.

```
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
   checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that is AlertDialog.